# Stop use of sql database after connecting - c#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently writing a class `DatabaseManager`, creating and deleting a Database separately works.

But in my tests, I'm creating and then deleting a database in one go, and I receive the error: `Cannot drop database "test" because it is currently in use`.

I managed to narrow the problem down to the following lines of code inside the createDatabase function

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    //a lot of irrelevant stuff (creating tables)
}
```

Deleting works completely fine without this - but I need a connection to create tables inside the database.

Comment: Well, it does solve the issue - but it is creating a new one. Now I cant create a new database after deleting one.

Comment: try to connect to master database and create from there

Comment: already doing that - otherwise creating a database wouldn't work

Comment: may be close and reopen connection and see if it works. I would suggest you to create new question, as this question, you have already got answer

Comment: the new mistake was on me (i forgot to open the connection) - will close the question, I completely overlooked the first answer. I even was on that exact page (:

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have no open connections to the database before dropping the database. Make sure your connection can optionally not connect to the database itself (just the server + master or something) to drop the test database.

Comment: using does exactly that - as stated in my question without these 3 lines of code everything works (I hope I understood you correctly)

Comment: Yes, But does your connection string include an initial catalog of "test"?

Comment: I suppose not (I'm quite new to working with SQL in c#)
`connectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = " + path + "\\" + name + ".mdf; Integrated Security=True";`

Comment: If you're using a LocalDB MDF, are you completely recreating the DB everytime? Maybe just delete the MDF instead of dropping?

Comment: Ehm, there are 2 problems with this:

1. you cant create a database with the same name again

2. its not really deleting the database and feels like bad code

Comment: The database is held in the MDF. If you delete the MDF after you're done, you can create the database over and over. That said, are you creating the database in your code or starting from a template MDF?